# How to determine performance capacity of an HPC, nodes vs CPUs

Tags: hpc

I am looking at two computing platforms. One is said to be a cluster and the other a minicluster.
pbsnodes -a on the cluster gives 40 nodes. But looking at the other specifications, the cluster core x sockets X threads gives 12 CPUs, the minicluster has 80. It looks to me as if the minicluster is actually higher performing than the cluster. I am not able to attach a file with the comparison of specifications.
Below are a few
HPC cluster

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                12
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-11
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    6
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 79
```

Minicluster

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              80
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-79
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  20
Socket(s):           2
NUMA node(s):        2
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               85
```

My question is where do the 40 nodes come in? And with so little CPUs on the cluster (12) how would its performance compare with the minicluster (80CPUs)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with pbsnodes but AFAIK `pbsnodes -a` provides the number of computing nodes, that is, thoroughly the number of HPC machine in the cluster.

Each machine has 1 or more socket. Each socket is composed of many core and each core can have multiple hardware threads. Hardware threads are also called logical core. They are sometimes also called "CPU" which is a very confusing terminology since a CPU is basically a (mico-)processor chip for many people (in fact some people also call "processor" a logical core too). The thing is that the terminology comes from decades ago where microprocessors have only 1 core.

NUMA nodes have nothing to do with actual HPC computing nodes. They are a set of logical core that share the same proximity with a given memory. Modern micro-processors can have multiple NUMA nodes in one chip (this is the case for Intel Skylake SP processors, Xeon-Phi and AMD Thread-Reapers for example). A NUMA node can also theoretically be a set of multiple microprocessors. NUMA architecture are complex but in your case, this point is not very relevant anyway.

In your "HPC cluster", there is apparently 40 computing nodes, composed of 2 socket each. Each socket contains 6 cores with 1 logical core per physical core (ie. no SMT, so no hyper-threading). The number of logical core per computing node is 2x6x1=12 which is the number of "CPU" reported.

In your "minicluster", the number of node is known (only 1?). There is apparently 2 sockets with 20 cores. Each physical core has 2 logical cores. The number of logical core per computing node is 2x20x2=80 which also matches with the number of "CPU" reported.

Note that the performance of an HPC machine is not directly related with the number of cores. Some HPC machine can have a lot of core and be pretty inefficient compared to one with fewer cores. This is dependent of other factor like the size of SIMD lanes, the SIMD instruction set, the frequency (which is variable), the instruction level parallelism and many more low-level properties.

The famous LINPACK benchmark is often used to measure the performance of an HPC machine though it generally provide an optimistic performance metric that does not match with the one you can expect from practical HPC applications (unless you do very intensive computations like large matrix multiplications). There are many benchmarks and none are perfect. The famous HPCG benchmark is more representative of actual numerical applications run on HPC machines. Note there is generally a huge gap between the performance of HPCG and LINPACK showing that practical application only use a fraction of the theoretically available computing power.

Comment: Thanks very much @Jérôme, I have learnt something. My calculations are very intensive (weather prediction).  I am having a lot of problems running the WRF (Weather Research and Forecasting) model on the cluster. I have used a 12-node cluster before, without any problem.  I still have to try the minicluster, which is why I asked.

Comment: Just a clarification: by intensive, I meant that the operational intensity, which is measured by the FLOPs/byte, is high. For example something like 20. In practice, many numerical codes do not have a very high value because it is very hard to get a high value as long as an application is working on double-precision numbers (8 bytes). Indeed, this means >100 operations per FP value which is huge. BLAS level 1 and 2 (eg vector operations and vector-matrix ones) result in a low intensity. For more information please read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roofline_model .